# Why is discord.js purge command not responding?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord.js bot. I'm getting stuck on the purge command. When I test it it either takes over a minute to respond *or* it doesn't work at all.

Javascript code:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
return message.reply("You don't have permssions to do that!");
if (!args[0])
  return message.channel.send(
    "Please enter a number of messages to clear! `Usage: .clear <amount>`"
  );
const deleteNum = parseInt(args[0])
if (isNaN(deleteNum)) return message.reply('that is not a number')
message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteNum).then(() => {
  message.channel
    .send(`**__Cleared ${args[0]} messages.__**`)
    .then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it just purge or is it all commands? If it is all commands then use this:

```js
message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms.`)
```

If the ping is high then it is an issue on your end. Else, you might need to look into more efficient/better ways of doing this. If you'd like to, you can reply with your ping and if it is not the ping's fault then I'd be happy to help anymore :D

Comment: The other commands work fine. It's just the purge command.

Comment: I have school rn, but in a few hours I will respond with some help on how I made my purge command as it does not have any issues.